# Substituition in second order differential equation $(D+\frac{1}{x})^2y=\frac{1}{x^2})$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Question

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad(D+\frac{1}{x})^2y=\frac{1}{x^2})$

I know it can be solved by Cauchy's method

In the following differential equation can we assume $(D+\frac{1}{x})y=\lambda$

and proceed to solve the differential equation in two step?

Using Bernoulli first order differential equation in each case?

If not, why?

Regards.

how to interconvert between

$y=\frac{c_{1} \cos \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln (x)\right)+c_{2} \sin \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \ln (x)\right)}{\sqrt{x}}+1$

which is an alternate answer and the one below?

[image]

here is the answer provided by symbolab.

Comment: The DE is just  $(x^2y')'=1$.  But your $\lambda$ should be a function of $x$ $(D+\frac{1}{x})y=\lambda (x)$

Comment: Yes you can solve it in two steps.

Comment: could you please post an answer because I am unable to get the correct answer

Comment: What answer didi you get ?

Comment: y=ln(cx)-1/c +c_1/x

Comment: well  $\ln (cx)=k+\ln x$ the constant $k$ is absobed by the othe constant that you have.

Comment: yes I realise that thanks for your help. This question appeared in our exam today and all my friends got trignometric terms in their answers i was baffled. Turns  out  I was right for once!

Comment: can you please help me interconvert between the above answer and the one you posted?

Comment: $1$ cant be a particular solution to the DE you posted.

Comment: I have posted the solution provided by symbolab.

Comment: Well there is a mistake somewhere because $1$ is not  valid particular solution to the DE you posted.

Comment: how can you determine that?

Comment: There is an extra $y$ in the equation symbolab is trying to solve

Comment: Your DE is $x^2y''+2xy'=1$ and the one you typed on Symbo is different with an extra $y$

Comment: Try to evaluate $(D+\dfrac 1 x)^2 (1)$ it's not equal to $ \dfrac 1 {x^2}$

Comment: (D^2x^2+2Dx+1)y right?. So y''x^2+2y'x+y=1

Comment: oh I see now. Thanks !

Comment: You're welcome  .......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(D+\frac{1}{x})^2y=\frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$(D+\frac{1}{x}) \lambda (x) =\frac{1}{x^2}$$
$$x \lambda' (x)+\lambda (x) =\frac{1}{x}$$
$$(x \lambda(x) )'=\dfrac 1x$$
$$\lambda (x)=\dfrac {\ln x}x + \dfrac Cx$$
Now substitute   $\lambda (x)=y'+\dfrac yx$ and solve the first order DE.
$$y'+\dfrac yx=\dfrac {\ln x}x + \dfrac Cx$$
$$xy'+y= {\ln x} +  C$$
$$(xy)'= {\ln x} +  C$$
$$xy= {x\ln x}-x+Cx+C_2$$
$$y(x)= {\ln x}+C_1+\dfrac {C_2}x$$